# Batch how do i output this into a text file?

Tags: batch-file

Here is my full code

```
set /p path=Please input the full directory: 
cls
echo Your directory is being scanned, please wait.
fciv -md5 -add %path% -r -type *.exe -type *.dll -type *.scr -type *.sys>files.txt
del fciv.err
for /F "tokens=2" %%a in ('findstr /G:Database.dll files.txt') do del "%%a"
cls
echo scan done, if anything from the directory was deleted, it was malware.
pause
```

It compares a database to a md5 list, I want to do something like this:

```
for /F "tokens=2" %%a in ('findstr /G:Database.dll files.txt') do del "%%a">>output.txt
start output.txt
```

I am trying to output what was deleted, if you need all the files I can give a link to them.

However this didnt work, I also tried the write command but I cant figure it out, does anyone have the answer?

Database.dll sample:

```
e1380dd9a68923b3768eecb35800b643
ed65254b46f8b5a496385061de9f649b
```

files.txt sample

```
4ee7861af63771a281d111c4c7df7bbe c:\$recycle.bin\$i868a60.exe
d39c033d26cfafe53d05010675df2efb c:\$recycle.bin\$irsklc2.exe
69efee893a1088e87788f416832576fc c:\$recycle.bin\$isqaig0.exe
54e91698a85a5bd24bfc69c1454b7719 c:\$recycle.bin\$ivdl1ao.exe
22c2abba3905e8179a356658f7ba43e9 c:\$recycle.bin\$rsqaig0.exe
```

Comment: So you want `output.txt` to contain a list of all files deleted by `del "%%a"`?

Comment: exactly. All deleted should be in output.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precede a `copy` command to see whether the file exists, then `del`-ete and `echo` it conditionally:

```
for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('findstr /G:Database.dll files.txt') do copy "%%~b" nul>nul && (del "%%~b" & echo %%~b)>>output.txt
```

The `del` command has no option to display a single deleted file unfortunately. In addition, it does not modify the `ErrorLevel`. So you need to work around like this.

---

**Note:**
Since `copy` is just *reading* the file for existence check, deleting it might still fail if you do not have sufficient access privileges. If that is important, you could use

```
for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('findstr /G:Database.dll files.txt') do move /Y "%%~b" "%TEMP%\%%~nxb">nul && (del "%TEMP%\%%~nxb" & echo %%~b)>>output.txt
```

inside of the `for` body alternatively.

Comment: You're welcome! I just added a **note** to my answer in case access restriction might occur...

Comment: That crashes my batch for some reason, is this correct?

for /F "tokens=2" %%a in ('findstr /G:Database.dll files.txt') move "%%a" "%TEMP%\%%a" %% (del "%TEMP%\%%a" & echo "%%a")>>output.txt

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo -- see my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32365057/3); the `%%` before `(del` should read `&&`...

Comment: now there is this error, please see the picture

https://gyazo.com/77308d1aeee5630f666dc212f5de0ae4

Comment: hmm... okay, I just added the _full_ command line in the note now... anyway, this seems to be something else... it would be helpful if you could provide some sample data of `files.txt` in your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32364795/5047996)... I'm not sure if you use `findstr` properly: `/G` instructs to read search strings from a _text_ file but you provided `Database.dll`, which I assume is a binary file; do you perhaps mean `Database.dll` to be a literal search string?

Comment: well the first code i posted will delete the things, the files.txt are .exe files from my computer. the database.dll is readable and not binary, the database contains md5 hashes of known malware. I think by now you know that this is an anti virus lol.

Comment: oh wait, the database is the one with the files we need to delete, not keep lol

Comment: output.txt is empty and the exe test files are still there.

Comment: Why use `copy` to check for existence?  Why not `IF EXIST %file% (do_stuff)`?

Comment: @RyanBemrose, `if` would work as well, of course; I chose `copy` though, because it is closer to the alternative `move` method I posted...

Comment: if i just open cmd and type findstr it says "FINDSTR: bad command line" and i can also find the actual file on my computer

Comment: Here is all the files if it can help

https://mega.nz/#F!WcVQ1DLT!XSqsQoLwfqrcUOppB591CA

Comment: I just had a quick look: 1. use `goto :eof` (note the colon); 2. when you `call` a sub-routine, you need to return to the main routine with `goto :eof` (or `exit /b`), but *not* with `goto :top` or something; execution continues after `call`, so you should state something like `call :sub & goto :top`...

Comment: sorry, i have been away. and i do know about this and i already fixed it.